# Drop down feature is not working in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have added a simple dropdown using the following code -:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav-menu d-none d-lg-block">
    <ul>
       <li class="active"><a href="#header">Dashboard</a></li>

       <li class="dropdown"><a href="#"><span>Drop Down</span> <i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i></a>
       <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Drop Down 1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Drop Down 2</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Drop Down 3</a></li>
       </ul>            
        </li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
```

And also added the following libraries :-

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

But my dropdown is not working. It is showing all the options 1 after the other like this :-
[image]

Comment: Can you share where have you added the scripts in your HTML or create a sandbox so that we can better understand the root cause. most probably, it's because of where you have placed your bootstrap/jQuery js

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some classes and HTML should be placed like that:

```html
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
      aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
        Action
      </a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
        Another action
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
        Something else here
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   
<div class="container">
  <h2>Multi-Level Dropdowns</h2>
  <p>In this example, we have created a .dropdown-submenu class for multi-level dropdowns (see style section above).</p>
  <p>Note that we have added jQuery to open the multi-level dropdown on click (see script section below).</p>                                        
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">New dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="test" href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```